# is it possible to play a tiktok in an iframe or div?

Tags: javascript, onclick, video-streaming

I am creating an array of objects corresponding for a different tiktok urls and ids i would like to reference and play when I call upon a given function.

I can't get the video to play though.

by itself will show the working video but I'm having difficulty interchanging the url and id to play different videos tied to an onclick to a button

below is what I have and not sure if there is an issue with my document.getElementById("visualDrinkMaker").src = ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tiktok</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <iframe id="drinkMaker" width="520" height="360"  frameborder="0" ></iframe>

    <div id="visualDrinkMaker">  

    </div>
    <button id="coffee">coffee</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     const drinksList = [
        coffee = {url: "https://www.tiktok.com/@traderjoesfoodreviews/video/6822687886077332741",
                id: "6822687886077332741"},
        latte = {url: "https://www.tiktok.com/@starseed137/video/6846913513248574725",
                id: "6846913513248574725"}
      ]
    document.getElementById("coffee").onclick =myFunction()

    function myFunction() {
      let url = drinksList[0].url;
      let id = drinksList[0].id;
     document.getElementById("visualDrinkMaker").src = '<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite=' + url + ' 
     data-video-id=' + id + ' style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> </section> 
     </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js">';
    }
   </script>;

  </body>
</html>
```